# Update UpdatePanel from called WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, webmethod

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#refreshDocuments').click(function () {
            var areaId = 42;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/TimeTest",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

...................

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

...................
Test.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private void TimeTest()
    {
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();``
    }
```

The TimeTest method is called when I press this button:

```
<id="refreshDocuments">Test</a>
```

My question is:
How can I update the label to fits my needs?

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any server control in UpdatePanel besides this link?

Comment: My bad. In my example, the link is outside the update panel. In the update panel actually are other controls which should be updated. The page is contains a GridView filled with data. The GridView is inside the UpdatePanel and outside are the filters. When a refresh button is pressed (the link in my example), the GridView should refresh the data. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I meant a label (my mistake). All the way, you can't refresh UpdatePanel in `TimeTest` method. Moreover, this method must be `public static` to allow call it asynchronously with `jQuery.ajax` method from JavaScript. Read more here: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

What you can do is to use `LinkButton` control and register it as an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for UpdatePanel and do all staff in this LinkButton's Click event handler

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="refreshDocuments" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="refreshDocuments" 
    Text="Click Me" OnClick="refreshDocuments_OnClick" />

protected void refreshDocuments_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //refresh controls in UpdatePanel1
    //UpdatePanel1 will be refreshed automatically
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this before, but the click refreshed all my page which wasn't good. I probably made a mistake. Now it works.